# Can I use the Boost.Range indexed adaptor in a non-const way?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to loop through a list, updating each element depending on the value of another list that shares indexes.

Ideally, I'd like to do this with a for-range loop like so:

```cpp
std::vector<int> is;
std::vector<int> other_list;

for (auto &i : is | boost::adaptors::indexed(0)) {
  i.value() = other_list[i.index()];
}
```

But I get an error like so:

```
indexed.cpp:29:48: error: invalid initialisation of non-const reference of type 'boost::range::index_value<int&, long int>&' from an rvalue of type 'boost::iterator_facade<boost::range_detail::indexed_iterator<__gne_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >, boost::range::index_value<int&, long int>, boost::random_access_traversal_tag, boost::range::index_value<int&, long in>, long int>::reference {aka boost::range::index_value<int&, long int>}'
```

Is what I'm after not possible with Boost.Range or am I simply doing it wrong?

**NB:** I also tried it with a `boost::combine` to no more luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`indexed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html) is a little funny in that it gives you a range who elements have a `value()` and an `index()`, rather than themselves being values. The key is that you don't actually need to take the `indexed` elements by reference - since the `value()`s themselves are modifiable.

For instance, if I were to change the example Boost provides:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::assign;
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    std::vector<int> input = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    for (const auto& element : input | indexed(0))
    {
        element.value() = 1;
    }

    for (int i : input) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`element` may be a reference to const, but I can still change all the values.

However, if `input` were a `const` range - *then* `value()` would itself be a reference to `const`, so this would not compile. As you'd expect.

Comment: yeah that worked, great! makes my mind hurt to look at that `const` though! :)

Comment: @SamKellett you don't need the const: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47acfcad59662b01

Comment: @sehe that's definitely better, although I still find it slightly misleading on first glance. maybe even `for (auto &&element : input | indexed(0))` (which is also fine) is even more intuitive.

Comment: Whatever you find reasonable, do that. Point is that `value()` is a reference to non-const iff the input range us non-const. I just made the element a const ref to emphasize that.

Comment: @Barry Same thing for reference captures in non-mutable lambdas, reference members in `const `member functions etc. It's really not that special. The only special thing here is _the iterator carries information_. Iterators themselves have value semantics by design

Comment: Is this answer correct? When I try it, "element" is a const int&, not an iterator (due to the C++11 for-range).

Comment: @Mael Yes it is, sehe even posted a link demonstrating it.

Comment: @Barry That's quite strange, because the exact same code, with the exact same compilation line, doesn't work here, neither on g++ nor clang++. Would you happen to know which Boost version you are using? I uses 1.55 (from the Ubuntu packages)

Comment: Just checked the boost documentation - the 'indexed' behavior changed in 1.56 (I thought that Boost was conservative about backward compatibility, but apparently not so much :)